# Numpy array memory usage issue

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, memory, neural-network

First, I'd like to say it is the first time I ever post a question here and I hope I won't break any rule, if so, feel free to correct me. I'll try to be as clear as possible.

I am implementing my own version of convolutional neural networks (CNN) and I'm facing an issue concerning numpy arrays. My implementation has been working and is still working, the problem is that my instanciation of CNN takes way more memory than a few hours ago. After trouble shooting I found out that only parameters in fully connected layer shows this problem (may be because it is way more heavy so that on convolutional layer the problem doesn't appear).
I loaded an older instanciation that I saved in order to illustrate. Both are numpy arrays with almost the same size:

```
>>> n.FCLay[0].theta.values.shape
(27744, 800)
>>> m.FCLay[0].theta.values.shape
(23064, 800)
```

n is the "big" CNN and m the "small" one (considering memory usage)

Moreover data they contain is the same type as shows this [screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Wyof.png)

However, when I look to the memory they use with [pympler's asizeof](https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/asizeof.html), this is what I get:

```
>>> asizeof.asizeof(n.FCLay[0].theta.values)
44390512
>>> asizeof.asizeof(m.FCLay[0].theta.values)
112
```

As you can see, the difference is quite huge.

So I've been trying different stuff:

```
>>> type(n.FCLay[0].theta.values) == type(m.FCLay[0].theta.values)
True

>>> n.FCLay[0].theta.values.nbytes
44390400
>>> m.FCLay[0].theta.values.nbytes
36902400
```

It seems like here size are comparable which I don't understand why if you reffer to asizeof results

```
>>> n.FCLay[0].theta.values.itemsize
2
>>> n.FCLay[0].theta.values.itemsize
2
```

Concerning Source code, this is how this values are initialized:

```
    self.values = np.random.randn
    self.values = np.random.randn(sizePrevLay, sizeNextLay)
    self.values *= sqrt(2.0/sizeInpt)
    self.values = self.values.astype(np.float16)
```

(The tests above give same results just after initialization and after proceeding some calculations)

Thank you for reading. I hope this is enough, please, feel free to ask for any precision.

Comment: In the mean time, I've been facing some changes in results I get for Error calculation (I was used to get 3.5 and get 9.0) but I don't know if this is related

Comment: I'm guessing `m` is a `view` and shares its data buffer with another array .